# Refresh DataTable after a remove() done

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, datatable

I've done a row `remove()` and then I tried to `fnDestroy()` and initialize back the **DataTable**. **The record count and the pagination does not effected(The **DataTable*** not refreshed)*.

I've also tried to use `fnDraw()` but it's still no use.

I've looked at the page source and the deleted row html is still there.

I'm using **Ajax** to delete the row. Appreciate your help

This is my delete script:

```
$(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('table#sample_1 td a.delete').click(function()
            {
                if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row?"))
                {
                    var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
                    var data = 'id=' + id ;
                    var parent = $(this).parent().parent();

                    $.ajax(
                    {
                           type: "POST",
                           url: "process.php",
                           dataType: "json",
                           data: data,
                           cache: false,

                           success: function()
                           {

                            var dtable = $('#sample_1').dataTable();
                        dtable.fnDestroy();


                        parent.fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});


                        //Reinitialize the datatable
                        $('#sample_1').dataTable({
                                    "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
                                    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
                                    "oLanguage": {
                                        "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page",
                                        "oPaginate": {
                                            "sPrevious": "Prev",
                                            "sNext": "Next"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "aoColumnDefs": [{
                                        'bSortable': false,
                                        'aTargets': [0]
                                    }]
                        });

                           }
                     });
                }
            });


        });


        </script>
```

Comment: try `$("element").hide().fadeIn('fast');`

Answer (score 2):

You can use fnDeleteRow to delete a row in the datatable. This function will automatically redraw the table.

Refer this, http://datatables.net/api

Comment: I'm trying to use ajax and some people also stated that even after doing fnDeleteRow, it does not referesh the table. And I'm also using checked box to delete the rows. Is there any other solution for this? Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 2):

It is going to cache all off the information in the initialization and when you try to do some actions ( i.e. sorting ) it will re-draw the table with existing data set. Therefore, you should use **draw( false )** to prevent re-drawing.

```
 table.row('.selectedRow').remove().draw( false );
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan you're right. I changed my answer. Thanks for bringing this into my attention.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
var rowid = document.getElementById(id);
var Pos = dt.fnGetPosition(rowid);
dt.fnDeleteRow(Pos);
```

Here id is unique row id which you want to delete.